# Catch and ignore/suppress errors in Mongoose post-save hook

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Is it possible to catch and ignore errors in a Mongoose post-save hook, resulting in a successful return (resp. a resolved promise) from a document `save` call?

Sample code:

```js
schema.post('save', function postSave(err, doc, next) {
  if (err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 12345) {
    // this does not work the way I'd expect it to
    return next();
  }
  return next(err);
});
```

The above hook still results in the `save` call failing with the original error (`next(null)` doesn't help either). I *can* replace the error by passing a custom one to `next`, which shows that the mechanism is generally working, but that doesn't really help me.

The [Mongoose middleware docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) contain a very similar example (see the "Error Handling Middleware" section near the bottom), but don't really explain the intended behavior of the `next` callback.

For context, what I'm trying to accomplish in the actual project is a post-save middleware hook that retries the save call when a duplicate key error is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

> However, there is a special kind of post middleware called "error handling middleware" that executes specifically when an error occurs. Error handling middleware is useful for reporting errors and making error messages more readable.

I think it is too late in the hooks chain to do this. It would seem that the `pre "save"` hook would be a good place to check for `duplicate keys` no? There you can error out and then in your code re-try as you see fit.

The `error handling middleware` is more of an error formatting mechanism really.

Comment: A pre-save hook wouldn't work for this use case, since there is always a (albeit tiny) chance that another process writes a document with the same key between the hook and the actual write call.

Explicitly retrying in calling code works, of course, but would be far less elegant than a middleware solution.

Thanks though! You're right, the docs kinda imply that this is not an intended use case.